# codeigniter data passed in form is lost after validating field

Tags: php, codeigniter

In one of my controllers i have the following piece of code, where i load a view (with a form) of a different model and pass some data to there.

```
$data['teste1']=$this->fichas_model->set_fichas();
$data['teste'] = $this->fichas_model->get_distribuidor();
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('aquitex/criar_ficha');
```

in the mentioned view, i then present the data passed like this:

```
<input type="input" name="id_ficha" value="<?php echo $teste1['id_ficha'];?>" />
<input type="input" name="nome_empresa" value="<?php echo $teste['nome_empresa'];?>" />
<input type="input" name="morada" value="<?php echo $teste['morada'];?>" />
```

which is working without no problem. The problem is with the validation fields i have in this form. If some validation is called (because i leave some field blank for example) i lost the data passed throught the $data['teste1'] e $data['teste'] arrays and get html code written on the inputs.

Here goes the code of the controller where the view is processed:

```
public function criar_ficha()
{

$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('nome_produto', 'Nome do Produto', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('morada', 'Morada', 'required');


if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{   
    $this->load->view('aquitex/criar_ficha', $data);
}
else
{
    $this->aquitex_model->set_ficha();
    $this->load->view('aquitex/success');
}
}
```

Hope i was clear in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use set_value method for this. [Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform) is the documentation.

```
<input type="input" name="id_ficha" value="<?php echo set_value('id_ficha',$teste1['id_ficha']);?>" />
```

The second parameter is default value and first parameter is the name of field. When validaton is failed first parameter will look for value if found display if not then take default value.
Also when validation is failed you should put all the lines only loading view will not work

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{   
    $data['teste1']=$this->fichas_model->set_fichas();
    $data['teste'] = $this->fichas_model->get_distribuidor();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('aquitex/criar_ficha');
}
```

Also note you are not passing `$data` to views. It should be

```
$this->load->view('aquitex/criar_ficha',$data);
```

Comment: I guess we are missing some ' or " in the echo set value in the form, because is not reading the value passed.

Comment: in the second part, i should alter the first two lines or i will be inserting data on db again. i should alter to get the values i previously obtained right?

Comment: Done. Thanks raheel shan. I solved the the problems following your tips.